# Replace a keyword in a web page with a hyperlink avoiding a and h tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following script that will replace keywords within a website with a hyperlink, but it's screwing up hyperlinks that already contain the keyword. How can I avoid replacing keywords that are within a and h tags?

```
<!-- include JQuery from Google CDN -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // https://findandreplace.bubbleapps.io/version-test/1.1/obj/keywords

        // set Async false for .each loop to work synchronously
        $.ajaxSetup({ async: false });

        txt = $('body').html(); 
        //alert (txt);

        $.ajax({
            url: "https://findandreplace.bubbleapps.io/version-test/api/1.1/obj/keywords",
            success: function(data){
                //console.log(data);
                $.each(data.response.results, function() {
                    keyword = this['keyword'];
                    url     = this['url'];

                    var regex = new RegExp(keyword, "ig");

                    replaceURL = "<a href='" + url + "'>" + keyword + "</a>";   
                    txt = txt.replace(regex, replaceURL);
                }); //end loop through keywords
                //alert("after keyword " + keyword + "----" + txt)
            } //end success function
        }); //end ajax call

        $('body').html(txt);

        //reset JS sync to true
        $.ajaxSetup({async: true}); 
    }); // end doc ready 

</script>
```

You can see an example here:  https://slybaldguys.com/keywordtest2.html

Comment: [Don't use regex on html](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1175966)

Comment: Also never ever use `async:false` for ajax. It is a horrible practice and browser vendors have deprecated it. You should be seeing a warning about that in browser dev tools console

Comment: @charlietfl any suggestions on what I should do to correct this?

Comment: What you will really need to do is iterate through text nodes in the document and only target them. A search for terms like "javascript or jquery replace text" should get you started

Comment: @charlietfl I've searched that and other variations hundreds of times and haven't found the answer I'm looking for, hence why I posted my question.